# Need help with water temperature differential equation problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A 50 liter water tank is full of 20°C water. We start using it, water flows out at 6 liters per minute. Also, 80°C water is flowing in at 2 liters per minute, which mixes completely, with the water already in the tank.

What is the temperature of the water flowing out?

I could solve other mixing problems with ODE-s, but I'm stuck with this one.

I guess the rate of change of temperature in the water tank is proportional to 80 minus current temperature. And the less water you have in the tank, the easier it is to change is temperature, but how do I go about solving it? This problem is from a calculus class.

Thanks

Comment: This one needs a bit of Physics knowledge. Heat energy = $mc\Delta T$, where c is the specific heat capacity and m is mass. By conservation of energy, there is no heat lost in the system containing the outlet, the inlet and the tank. That should give you an idea. (Btw the value of c here is irrelevant as water is the only substance involved and we only need to find the temperature.

Comment: Also it is helpful to think about the heat change that occurs in a small timestep $\Delta t$.

Comment: Still can't solve it.

Comment: Have you done problems like this with dissolved salt? This is just like that, but you need to convert temperature to heat energy.